# Getting an error using Beautifulsoup find_all() .get('href')

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a html for links under a specific class called "category-list"
Each link reside under a h4 tag(I'm ignoring its parent h3 tag):

```
<ul class="category-list">
      <li class="category-item">
       <h3>
        <a href="/derdubor/c/alarm_og_sikkerhet/">
         Alarm og sikkerhet
        </a>
       </h3>
       <ul>
        <li>
         <h4>
          <a href="/derdubor/c/alarm_og_sikkerhet/brannsikring/">
           <span class="category-has-customers">
            Brannsikring
           </span>
           (1)
          </a>
         </h4>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </li>
```

...

My code for scraping the html is the following:

```
r = request.urlopen(str_top_url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.read(),'html.parser')

tag_category_list = soup.find('ul', class_ = 'category-list')

tag_items = tag_category_list.find_all('h4')

for tag_item in tag_items.find_all('a'):
    print(tag_item.get('href'))
```

I get the error:

```
"ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item..."
```

Reading the BeautifulSoup manual on crummy, it looks like you can use the same methods belonging to the BeautifulSoup class on a tag object?
I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong...

I've tried numerous answers her on stackoverflow. But to no avail...

Regards MH

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in this line `for tag_item in tag_items.find_all('a'):`. You should first iterate through tag_items and the through find_all('a') items. Here is the edited code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('<ul class="category-list"><li class="category-item"><h3><a href="/derdubor/c/alarm_og_sikkerhet/">Alarm og sikkerhet</a></h3><ul><li><h4><a href="/derdubor/c/alarm_og_sikkerhet/brannsikring/"><span class="category-has-customers">Brannsikring</span>(1)</a></h4></li></ul></li>','html.parser')

tag_category_list = soup.find('ul', class_ = 'category-list')

tag_items = tag_category_list.find_all('h4')

for elm in tag_items:
    for tag_item in elm.find_all('a'):
        print(tag_item.get('href'))
```

And here is the result:
`/derdubor/c/alarm_og_sikkerhet/brannsikring/`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `tag_items` is a `ResultSet`, not a `Tag`.

From [the Beautiful Soup documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#miscellaneous):

> `AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'foo'` - This usually happens because you expected `find_all()` to return a single tag or string. But `find_all()` returns a *list* of tags and strings–a `ResultSet` object. You need to iterate over the list and look at the `.foo` of each one. Or, if you really only want one result, you need to use `find()` instead of `find_all()`.

So this nested loop should work:

```
for tag_item in tag_items:
    for link in tag_item.find_all('a'):
        print(link.get('href'))
```

Or, if you were only expecting one `h4`, change `find_all('h4')` to `find('h4')`.

Comment: Aah! The fact that tag_items returns a list was lost on me! It works like a charm now. ;) should have done more research I see :(